# ASP.NET Report Viewer Photos

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I need to create a report with Report Viewer to show a list of my employees. For each employee I need to show the personnal data and the photo. 
The photo is stored in disk within the server. Also the photo is coded using an algorithm and based in the employee id (integer).

I have already the report, taking all the data from the database. 
The only problem is to show the photos.

This is ASP.NET c#

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in showing photos exactly?

Comment: #martinwnet: Yes, I have tried, if you want to help...help, if not, please go to another question

Comment: Thanks Buzz, the problem is I can't show the photos. I don't know where I have to write the code to access the photo of each employee.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement a service which will read and return the photo based on some type of parameters.

For example http://mydomain.com/getphoto/100500 (where 100500 is an ID).

So you just need to add  tag to your output.

Also you can use ready ASP.NET reporting component. There are a lot of them available. For example you can use
[SharpShooter Reports](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Web.aspx) (it's our product so I placed it first :) and other reporting software (to be fair) such as [Telerik reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx), [Active Reports](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/) from Component One, etc.

However these components have significant cost so I would not use it if I didn't need complicated reporting solution.